# For fermion, is charge conjugate operator $C$ an anti-unitary operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, operators, fermions, charge-conjugation

In condensed matter theory, $C$ is called "particle-hole inversion", such that $C^2=-1$, for fermionic state.

In high energy physics, just like most of the QFT textbooks, $C$ is introduced from Dirac field, satisfies $C^2=1$, even for fermionic state.

I am confused, maybe I make some mistakes above?

Which one is correct?

Comment: Wigner's theorem fixes $C$ up to a phase. Both are correct and unitary but $C_{cond.matt.}= iC_{hep}$

Comment: Maybe a reason for the difference is that in QFT one wants to have $C$ representing also an observables and $C$ is therefore defined in order to satisfy $C^*=C$ and thus the unitarity condition reads $CC=I$.